# Can't decode embedded documents (nested) from MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, go, decode, bson

I need to get a document from MongoDB and put it into a struct with custom type.

```
type translate_t struct {
    Sources     []string    `bson:"sources"`
    Targets     []string    `bson:"targets"`
}

type practice_t struct {
    Id              primitive.ObjectID  `bson:"_id"`
    Translate       translate_t         `bson:"translate"`
}
```

The data in the database is as expected.

```
"practice": {
    "translate": {
         "sources": ["data", "more data"]
         "target": ["even", "more", "data"]
    }       
}
```

What I do (very basic):

```
var item practice_t
err = collection.FindOne(ctx, filter).Decode(&item)
log.Printf("item:%+v", item)
```

The log prints this:

```
{Id:ObjectId("5deeblablabla"), Translate:{Sources:[] Targets:[]}} //where is my sweet data?
```

Now, I want to point out that **all the other items** (not nested with custom struct) **get decoded properly**. So, it seems to me that the Decode() function doesn't like custom structs...
This looks like a very common task, so am I missing anything?
I've been reading about overriding the default Decoder or something like that, but that seems way too much work for something this simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing "practice":

```
type doc struct {
  Practice practice_t `bson:"practice"`
}
```

The database document has to structurally match the document you're unmarshaling. You showed the database document is an object with a `practice` field. Then you must have a struct with a field tagged with `practice`.

Comment: Oh, the sweet, sweet data!